# create cucumber java testng maven executable jar project and run from command line

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, testng

I created my project in Intellij idea with maven set up.

Just I want to build executable jar with complete dependencies and run through command line.

Ex: java -jar hello.jar

Answer (score -1):

An example can be found in my blog post [Create an executable jar from Maven](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2011/03/05/create-an-executable-jar-from-maven)

Just make sure you can run Cucumber from your main function.